# System.getProperty() on a server

Tags: java

I'm using System.getProperty("user.name") to get the name of localuser. It works fine and now my class need to work on server.

Unfortunately, System.getProperty("user.name") try to catch the user name of the server and return "root".

Is it possible using System.getProperty() I get the name of localuser running the class on the server? If not, is there any way?

Comment: Apparently, for some insane reason the server *is* running as root.

Comment: You already have, it's running as `root` which is the super-user (e.g. Administrator) on UNIX systems.

Comment: But when i run on my computer, as localuser, it return for exemple "Fillipe", not "root".

Comment: @FillipeSanches *root* and *Fillipe* are two different users, and your computer has both. It it just the case that you log in as *Fillipe*. Since your program doesn't need administrator privileges to run, you run it as *Fillipe* and that's what it returns. Apparently, the server is running as the administrator (instead of a normal user), and that's why you're getting *root*.

Answer (score 1):

`System.getProperty("user.name")` returns user's account name on which the java process is running. As you mentioned on your local computer you are running it on user "Filiipe" however on server you are running it as a root user. Maybe you are using tomcat/jboss started automatically as a system service, that kind of services are running under root user.

You can also easily check it with `ps -ef` command on linux - the first column is user that started the service.

You can also try override this parameter by adding additional option to your server starting script `-Duser.name=Fellipe`. I didn't try it but it may work.